# Solving a steady state temperature distribution problem with the help of Hankel Transform

Tags: integral-transforms

Could someone please help me with the following problem. I am totally new to Hankel Transform. This question is my first assignment related to Hankel transform. I tried to solve it but couldn't get the desired result. I shall be thankful if someone could point out my mistake or help me with completing my solution.  Here is the question and my attempt. Thank you.
**Question**
The steady temperature distribution $u(r,z)$ in a semi-infinite solid with $z\geq{0}$ is governed by the system \begin{align}
u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_{r}+u_{zz}=-Aq(r),\qquad 0<r<\infty, \quad z>0\label{ii}\\
u(r,0)=0\label{iii}
\end{align} where $A$ is a constant and $q(r)$ represents the steady heat source. Show that the solution is given by $$u(r,z)=A\int_{0}^{\infty}\tilde{q}(k)J_{0}(kr)k^{-1}(1-e^{-kz})dk,$$ where $\tilde{q}(k)$ is the zeroth-order Hankel transform of $q(r)$.
**Solution:**
The steady temperature distribution $u(r,z)$ in a semi-infinite solid with $z\geq{0}$ is governed by the system $$u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_{r}+u_{zz}=-Aq(r),\qquad 0<r<\infty, \quad z>0$$ $$u(r,0)=0$$. As asked in question, we have to find $u(r,z)$ by the method of Hankel transform of zero-order. So let $\tilde{u}(k,z)$ be the zero-order Hankel transform of $u(r,z)$, i.e., $$\tilde{u}(k,z)=\mathcal{H}_{0}\{u(r,z)\}=\int_{0}^{\infty}ru(r,z)J_{0}(kr)dr$$ Applying zero-order Hankel transform on both sides of equation $\ref{ii}$, we have: \begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}r\left(u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_{r}+u_{zz}\right)J_{0}(kr)dr=\int_{0}^{\infty}r\left(-Aq(r)\right)J_{0}(kr)dr\\
\mathcal{H}_{0}\left\{\left(u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_{r}\right)\right\}+\int_{0}^{\infty}ru_{zz}J_{0}(kr)dr=-A\int_{0}^{\infty}r\left(q(r)\right)J_{0}(kr)dr\\
\text{from properties of Hankel transform}\\
-k^{2}\tilde{u}(k,z)+\frac{d^{2}}{dz^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}ru(r,z)J_{0}(kr)dr=-A\mathcal{H}_{0}\{q(r)\}\\
-k^{2}\tilde{u}(k,z)+\frac{d^{2}}{dz^{2}}\mathcal{H}_{0}\{u(r,z)\}=-A\tilde{q}(k)\\
-k^{2}\tilde{u}(k,z)+\frac{d^{2}}{dz^{2}}{\tilde{u}(k,z)}=-A\tilde{q}(k)
\end{align*}
rearranging the above equation, we get
\begin{align}\label{iv}
\frac{d^{2}}{dz^{2}}{\tilde{u}(k,z)}-k^{2}\tilde{u}(k,z)=-A\tilde{q}(k)\\
f(D)(\tilde{u}(k,z))=\left(D^{2}-k^{2}\right)(\tilde{u}(k,z)=-A\tilde{q}(k) \notag\\
\end{align}
equation \ref{iv} is 2nd order, linear, non-homogeneous ODE. The given conditions under the Hankel transform is \begin{align}
\mathcal{H}_{0}\{u(r,0)\}=\mathcal{H}_{0}\{0\}\notag\\
\tilde{u}(k,0)=0\label{v}
\end{align}
Now, solving, $\ref{iv}$ with the  help of $\ref{v}$. The associated homogeneous equation to $\ref{iv}$ is $$\frac{d^{2}}{dz^{2}}{\tilde{u}(r,z)}-k^{2}\tilde{u}(k,z)=-A\tilde{q}(k)$$ and hence the solution is $$\tilde{u}_{c}(k,z)=c_{1}e^{-kz}+c_{2}e^{kz}$$ Now, the solution of non-homogeneous part is \begin{align*}
\tilde{u}_{p}(k,z)&=\frac{1}{f(D)}(-A\tilde{q}(k))\\
&=\frac{-A\tilde{q}(k)}{\left(D^{2}-k^{2}\right)}e^{0}\\
&=\frac{-A\tilde{q}(k)}{\left(0-k^{2}\right)}e^{0}\\
&=\frac{-A\tilde{q}(k)}{-k^{2}}\\
&=\frac{A\tilde{q}(k)}{k^{2}}
\end{align*}
Thus the solution of equation $\ref{iv}$ is \begin{align}\label{vi}
\tilde{u}(k,z)=c_{1}e^{-kz}+c_{2}e^{kz}+\frac{A\tilde{q}(k)}{k^{2}}
\end{align}
Applying the given condition, $\tilde{u}(k,0)=0$ to above solution equation:
\begin{align*}
\tilde{u}(k,0)&=c_{1}e^{-k0}+c_{2}e^{k0}+\frac{A\tilde{q}(k)}{k^{2}}\\
0&=c_{1}+c_{2}+\frac{A\tilde{q}(r)}{k^{2}}\\
\implies c_{1}&=-c_{2}-\frac{A\tilde{q}(k)}{k^{2}}
\end{align*} Thus solution $\ref{vi}$ is, now,
\begin{align*}
\tilde{u}(k,z)&=(-c_{2}-\frac{A\tilde{q}(r)}{k^{2}})e^{-kz}+c_{2}e^{kz}+\frac{A\tilde{q}(k)}{k^{2}}\\
&=-c_{2}e^{-kz}-\frac{A\tilde{q}(r)}{k^{2}}e^{-kz}+c_{2}e^{kz}+\frac{A\tilde{q}(k)}{k^{2}}\\
\tilde{u}(k,z)&=c_{2}\left(e^{kz}-e^{-kz}\right)+\frac{A\tilde{q}(k)}{k^{2}}(1-e^{-kz})\\
\text{applying Hankel inverse on both sides}\\
u(r,z)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}kc_{2}(e^{kz}-e^{-kz})J_{0}(kr)dk+\int_{0}^{\infty}k\frac{A\tilde{q}(k)}{k^{2}}(1-e^{-kz})J_{0}(kr)dk\\
&=c_{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}k(e^{kz}-e^{-kz})J_{0}(kr)dk+A\int_{0}^{\infty}k^{-1}{\tilde{q}(k)}(1-e^{-kz})J_{0}(kr)dk\\
&=c_{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}k(e^{kz}-e^{-kz})J_{0}(kr)dk+A\int_{0}^{\infty}{\tilde{q}(k)}J_{0}(kr)k^{-1}(1-e^{-kz})dk\\
\end{align*}